# Cluster Shared Volume error after server not shutting down properly

Tags: windows-cluster, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

We have two IBM X240 servers (call them server A and server B) connecting to IBM disk system:V3700 via fibre HBA.

The both servers are installing windows 2012 R2.

We have implemented VM cluster and everything is working well.

Last week this two server is down due to power shortage in my server room.

After turning on the  server A, it will come out the below error:

> Windows failed to start, a recent hardware or software change might be
>   cause. File: \windows\system32\drivers\msdsm.sys status: 0xc0000017
>   Info:the operation system could't be loaded because a critical system
>   drive is missing or contain errors.

After using the Last Good Configuration, we can log in to the system and turn on the clustered virtual machine.

It seems everything is fine now.

So I go and start the server B and log in to the system using the same method with server A.

I found all the VM will be shut down or running error due to Cluster Shared Volume error.

Refer to below some errors captured from system system logs.

> Event 5142, Cluster Shared Volume 'Volume7' ('Cluster Disk 10') is no
>   longer accessible from this cluster node because of error '(1460)'.
>   Please troubleshoot this node's connectivity to the storage device and
>   network connectivity.
>
> Event 5120,Cluster Shared Volume 'Volume3' ('Cluster Disk 4') has
>   entered a paused state because of '(c00000be)'. All I/O will
>   temporarily be queued until a path to the volume is reestablished.

Now we only can turn on only one server and shut down another server, if I turn on both server, the error will come out again & the server will go down.

Any suggestion or need me provide more information.

***Updated information on 28.05.15:***

i think the issue is unable to access a CSV volume from a passive (non-coordinator) node.

i also refer to below document but it also can not solve my issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2008795?wa=wsignin1.0

Refer to below result when turning on both nodes or any one node using cmdlet:get-clustershardvolumestate

*When turning on both nodes:
[image]

When turning on any one node:
[image]

I Also upgrade the both nodes vendor DSM drivers, but the result is the same.

Comment: Hi,
Any advise on this?

Comment: Hi, i also try to reinstall the DSM drviers on both nodes, but the result is the same.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, 
Who can help me on this issue or need me to provide any more information?
Thanks.

Comment: We aren't your helpdesk and we don't offer technical support for your problems. Stop "bumping" your question asking for help. If someone has an answer, they'll post it. If this is a business critical issue go here and open a support case: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus?ws=support